# Pandas read_excel: only read first few lines

Tags: pandas

Using pandas read_excel on about 100 excel files - some are large - I want to read the first few lines of each (header and first few rows of data).

This doesn't work but illustrates the goal (example reading 10 data rows):

```
workbook_dataframe = pd.read_excel(workbook_filename, nrows = 10)
```

This is my current workaround:

```
workbook_dataframe = pd.read_excel(workbook_filename).head(10)
```

Problem with the workaround is it has to read the entire excel file before taking the head.  I've also tried experimenting with skiprows and skip_footer, giving it negative numbers which just produces errors.

Comment: Are you open to use other libraries such as [openpyxl](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/optimized.html)?

Comment: I've had a brief look - is there a way to partially read an excel file as per the question?

Comment: Yes. The optimized [read-only](http://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/optimized.html) mode allows to do this.

Comment: OK - found this - but not how to specify how many rows to load:  `wb = load_workbook(filename='large_file.xlsx', read_only=True)`

Comment: You can slice the worksheet: `ws = wb.active; ws['A1:C3']`. Or iterate over rows/cols and with a fixed range (e.g. `range(10)`)

Comment: This is honestly an excellent question, I am surprised there aren't any inbuilt solutions for this in pandas. Were you able to find a workaround within pandas?

Comment: @Jan Trienes your library page does not seem to work

Comment: @Aetos it seems that this particular page is no longer available. However, [openpyxl](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) still exists.

Comment: The functionality is now active, but notice that there is no difference in timing. I guess the function reads the whole sheet and then return only some rows.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't currently supported although looking at the code it doesn't look like it should be too hard. You can open an issue on the Github project page at https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues.

Comment: Opened issue #16645